# Is there any well documented Redmine installation process

Tags: redmine

is there any well documented step by step procedure to install redmine?. I tried to install it on my Ubuntu machine.But i am unable to access it from another machine. please tell me how to it. is there any document which show how to host as centralized

Answer (score 0):

See this guide: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/redmineinstall. Its a general installation guide. I used it to install Redmine on Debian Jessie.

Comment: thanks @Nadir Latif. I am able to install it but how to host it as centralized?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by hosting it as centralized

Comment: In our organisation, around 60-80 people need to use this. currently only single person is able to use this. Is there anyway so that all the people can use it?

Comment: Well, Redmine is a full featured project management and collaboration platform. It supports users, groups and roles. You can install Redmine on a public server or on your corporate intranet. Redmine is written in Ruby language, so hosting it is more difficult than for Php based websites. It is easy to setup Redmine on Cloud platforms such as Google Cloud or AWS

Comment: Okay. Is there any other way to do it not the cloud one?

Comment: Well there is easyredmine: https://www.easyredmine.com/redmine-hosting/. EasyRedmine is a comerical version of Redmine. It also provides hosting services